# Id could not be found in Datalist on click of upload button

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, datalist

I have one page where I am making use of Update panel, Datalist and file upload. **I am using visual studio 2010**.

My fileupload is in data list and I am binding data list with dynamic table to repeat the file upload control.

Please see below layout image:

[image]

Here Main upper red highlighted border is showing the repeated data list and in that I have file upload control.

Now the data list is in Update Panel so the file upload was not working **So in data list I have taken another update panel to make file upload work** and that was also working properly but on clicking of green add button issue started arising as

> A control with ID 'Upload' could not be found for the trigger in
>   UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Below is my html code and please remember I am just giving the part where issue is arises:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Uppanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataList ID="dtcustomerregistration" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
            Width="100%" OnItemCommand="dtcustomerregistration_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Pic">
                            Upload Image:</label>

                        <asp:FileUpload ID="Pic" runat="server" accept="image/gif, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" />

                        <asp:Button ID="Upload" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("uniqueId") %>' CommandName="Edit"
                            runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload_Click" />
                        <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" CssClass="requiredvalidate" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdimagename" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("UploadImage") %>' />

                        <asp:Image ID="imgpicuploaded" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowImagetemppath"].ToString().Replace("~/","") +Eval("UploadImage").ToString() %>'
                            Height="50px" />
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Upload" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgplus" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/Add.png" Height="50px" OnClick="imgplus_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My code on imgplus click event is as below.

```
protected void imgplus_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
int n = (int)ViewState["n"];
n = n + 1;
BindData(n);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
ViewState["data"] = null;
BindData(0);
}
}
public void BindData(int n)
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("uniqueId");
dt.Columns.Add("Invoice");
dt.Columns.Add("ReturnType");
dt.Columns.Add("ItemNumber");
dt.Columns.Add("ReturnQTY");
dt.Columns.Add("UnitofMeasure");
dt.Columns.Add("CreditPer");
dt.Columns.Add("ReasonCode");
dt.Columns.Add("InvoiceNumber");
dt.Columns.Add("Ordernumber");
dt.Columns.Add("Notes");
dt.Columns.Add("UploadImage");

if (ViewState["data"] == null)
{
dt = bindemptydata(dt, n);
}
else
{
foreach (DataListItem dli in dtcustomerregistration.Items)
{
HiddenField lblid = (HiddenField)dli.FindControl("lblid");
DropDownList RetCred = (DropDownList)dli.FindControl("RetCred");
DropDownList returntype = (DropDownList)dli.FindControl("returntype");
TextBox ItemNumber = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("ItemNumber");
TextBox ReturnQty = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("ReturnQty");
DropDownList Unit = (DropDownList)dli.FindControl("Unit");
TextBox Credit = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("Credit");
DropDownList ReasonCode = (DropDownList)dli.FindControl("ReasonCode");
TextBox Invoice = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("Invoice");
TextBox OrderNumber = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("OrderNumber");
TextBox Notes = (TextBox)dli.FindControl("Notes");
Image imgpicuploaded = (Image)dli.FindControl("imgpicuploaded");
HiddenField hdimagename = (HiddenField)dli.FindControl("hdimagename");
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

if (lblid.Value != "")
{
dr["uniqueId"] = lblid.Value;
}
else
{
dr["uniqueId"] = n;
}
dr["Invoice"] = RetCred.SelectedValue;
dr["ReturnType"] = returntype.SelectedValue;
dr["ItemNumber"] = ItemNumber.Text;
dr["ReturnQTY"] = ReturnQty.Text;
dr["UnitofMeasure"] = Unit.SelectedValue;
dr["CreditPer"] = Credit.Text;
dr["ReasonCode"] = ReasonCode.SelectedValue;
dr["InvoiceNumber"] = Invoice.Text;
dr["Ordernumber"] = OrderNumber.Text;
dr["Notes"] = Notes.Text;
dr["UploadImage"] = hdimagename.Value;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

dt = bindemptydata(dt, n);
}
BindDatalist(dt);
ViewState["n"] = n;
}

public DataTable bindemptydata(DataTable dt, int n)
{
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["uniqueId"] = n;
dr["Invoice"] = "Credit";
dr["ReturnType"] = "0";
dr["ItemNumber"] = "";
dr["ReturnQTY"] = "";
dr["UnitofMeasure"] = "Each";
dr["CreditPer"] = "100%";
dr["ReasonCode"] = "0";
dr["InvoiceNumber"] = "";
dr["Ordernumber"] = "";
dr["Notes"] = "";
dr["UploadImage"] = "";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

return dt;
}
public void BindDatalist(DataTable dt)
{
dtcustomerregistration.DataSource = dt;
dtcustomerregistration.DataBind();// Here I am receiving error
ViewState["data"] = dt;
}
```

Here above I had given full code to create the dynamic data table and binding that with data list so that data list get repeated on click of `imgplus` button 
But on click of button I am receiving error as :

Below is the error image.
[image]

**How can I fix this?**

On Click on `Imgplus` button I m receiving issue for upload button which exist in DataList.

And one more thing that if I normally click `ImgPlus` button without having use of Upload button click then it will repeat the DataList control without giving any issue but in case Once I made use of Upload click button exist in DataList and then after I click `Imgplus` button I receive error as:

> A control with ID 'Upload' could not be found for the trigger in
>   UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting your rendered HTML code just to be sure that your button has the ID you think? First check that, can help you.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Upload" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("uniqueId") %>' CommandName="Edit"
                            runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload_Click" />

here Upload id is there

Comment: Your rendered code, not your designer code. Run your solution and with Chrome Dev Tools (for example), inspect your DOM elements.

Comment: as the update panel is there it change the id of Upload button so how can I resolve this issue

Comment: and also in this case there are 2 update panel one inside datalist and second outside the datalist

Comment: Try to change this: <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Upload" /> Put the rendered ID instead of "Upload".

Comment: how it is possible possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160104/discussion-between-jcm-and-xtremcool).

Answer (score 0):

Surround your button with another UpdatePanel `upButton`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upButton" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <asp:Button ID="Upload" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("uniqueId") %>' CommandName="Edit"
        runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
```

And then call your main UpdatePanel `Uppanel.Update();` in your button click method `Upload_Click`.

**Note:** Remove UpdatePanel `ID="UpdatePanel1"`.

Comment: But I am facing issue on img plus button

Comment: try it for that button simply

Comment: OK I will try it and let u know 
But sure u read my question properly and ready my issue

I am receiving error as 
A control with ID 'Upload' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1

Comment: I had tried what you told but same issue is coming, The issue is on imgplus button and not on Upload button

Answer (score 0):

You're error happens because of this code:

```
<Triggers>
         <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Upload" />
</Triggers>
```

You used  `PostBackTrigger` while you are inside a nested pannel, while you shoud use 
`AsyncPostBackTrigger` in this case as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) page.

So change that code segment to be:

```
<Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Upload" />
</Triggers>
```

or set the `UpdateMode` of `UpdatePanel1` to be `"Always"`

Comment: on setting AsyncPostBackTrigger the file on the upload control will not get found

Comment: Clould you try to remove the UpdatePanel1 AND setting the trigger to be AsyncPostBackTrigger?.. You put the nested UpdatePanel1 to make the upload work at the first place with the synchronous PostBackTrigger. I tried to replicate the bug but didn't work, however I noticed that the designer didn't notice the Upload button when I chose PostBackTrigger + the link that I posted noted something about the nested update panels and PostBackTrigger.

Comment: Actually I am working on visual studio 2010 it is giving the current issue. when I copy this code to visual studio 2015 it is working fine, so I think my issue is of versioning